# How come I can still receive data when all my ports are closed?

Tags: networking, port

I launched an AWS instance with no inbound ports open, except 22.

How come I can still execute commands like these and receive responses:

`curl google.com`

`apt install apache`

`ping google.com`

How is the data reaching my server?

Comment: are you trying to execute commands from ssh ?

Answer (score 3):

The firewall in use is [stateful](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stateful_firewall) and will be configured to allow packets in, if they are related to an outbound flow. Thus, when you connect out using curl, the responses to your request are allowed in.